# how to redirect the vmstat's output to a file in Android OS?

Tags: android, shell, redirect, android-ndk, adb

I connect to my rooted phone through adb shell command and I run
the **vmstat** command so as to watch various system resources. Is
there a way to redirect vmstat's output to a file. I tried:

```
vmstat > /sdcard/vmstat_output.txt
```

but it doesn't work.. It creates the file but there is no data inside..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I fixed the problem. I download the source from [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/attachmentText?id=17996&aid=179960000000&name=vmstat.c&token=795cfaef27ae3d19ba2784afdf94a61f) and I added one extra line:

```
fflush(stdout);
```

right after the print_line command (line: 134). Then, I cross-compiled the vmstat.c with
[agcc](http://android-tricks.blogspot.com/2009/02/hello-world-c-program-on-using-android.html):

```
agcc vmstat.c -o vmstat
```

and put the file to the /sdcard/ through the adb:

```
adb push vmstat /sdcard/
```

Now the redirection works
perfectly, as after every print_line call, the data are flushed to the file. As Mark Polhamus mentioned,
the problem was the fact that vmstat is a block-buffered command, which means that a buffer
has to be filled with data first and then this data will be flushed to the file..

Thank you very much Mark! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the output from vmstat is block-buffered when redirected to a file.  So vmstat would have to write a blocks worth of data before it is flushed to the file, and if you interrupt it before it has written enough then the file is empty.  If you wait long enough you should have some output (worked for me).

You could have vmstat terminate itself (flushing the data) after writing a few lines with the "-n " flag, but that feature seems to be broken.

/proc/vmstat, /proc/stat, and /proc/meminfo have the same information I believe, just not formatted nicely like with vmstat.

Comment: Thank you! This seems to make sense.. Is it possible to change the blocks of data needed  to be filled before the flush? e.g. through a configuration file, or alternatively, through changing and cross compiling the vmstat's source code? Another way I can think is to force the stdout to be redirected to a file for all the running processes.. e.g. through log.redirect-stdio, link [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#stdout).

Comment: Filed bug report [link](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17996) for broken vmstat -n flag.

Comment: If you compile your own version of vmstat you could change the buffering for stdout using setbuf or setvbuf, or just call fflush after each write.

Comment: Not sure about log.redirect-stdio, looks like that is for vm output only, not output from processes started from a shell.

Comment: FWIW `adb shell vmstat | tee logfile.txt` works on Linux and is an okay workaround.

Comment: yes, but I want to do it without having the phone connected with the computer through the USB.. I will try to compile the source code and change the buffer size..

Comment: I want to keep track of the CPU load.. The top command produces bigger output that vmstat, so it flushes its data to the file more frequently. Maybe I can use this instead of vmstat, but maybe top consumes much more CPU than vmstat.. Am I right??

Answer (score 1):

I usually redirect it directly to my local machine via

```
adb shell vmstat -r 0 -d 1 > ~/tmp/vmstat.log
```

with help of the **-s** switch on `adb` you can select the device and thus log several connected devices simultaneously to separate logs.